# Different energies for two different geometries where only the monolayer c lattice constant is different?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I carried out a simple single-point PBE calculation on two different graphene monolayers (only `c` is different) using VASP with 12x12x1 k-grid.

Geometry 1:

```
graphene
1.0
1.22800000 -2.12695839  0.00000000
1.22800000  2.12695839  0.00000000
0.00000000  0.00000000  25
2
direct
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.25000000
   0.33333333  0.66666667  0.25000000
```

Geometry 2:

```
graphene
1.0
1.22800000 -2.12695839  0.00000000
1.22800000  2.12695839  0.00000000
0.00000000  0.00000000  100
2
direct
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.25000000
   0.33333333  0.66666667  0.25000000
```

I get two different energy results and a different number of maximum number of plane waves from the output. Why? Since they don't have periodicity on the z-direction how this effects?

Is there a protocol to follow for 2D materials calculations in VASP? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A VASP calculation will always have periodicity in all three spatial directions. The reason you are building a large vacuum in the z-direction is to minimize the interaction between periodic images so that you approach the true non-periodic limit. The vacuum space in the z-direction becomes a convergence parameter against which you need to test your results.

Comment: +1. But please do look at the edits I made as it is important to make your best possible effort at writing a clean and understandable, grammatically correct question.

Comment: Yeah but isn't both 25A and 100A enough to eliminate these interactions? Also, I don't understand how number of maximum plane waves for 100A one is 3,4 times bigger than 25A one? Since when I use this number for `NBANDS keyword` for GW calculations, it ridiculously requires more memory.

Comment: As your coordinates are in fractional format, changing the cell parameters automatically change the atom positions, so, there are two different cell with atoms in different positions. This imply in different system energy.

Comment: This material is planar though so that fractional format won't matter for these calculations (it will as soon as you have atoms out of that plane though). @Alfred can you clarify what energy differences you are seeing?

Comment: These geometries are just for giving you an idea. My input geometries are in Cartesian coordinate and optimised. The energy difference is something like 0.8 eV, and the number of maximum wave planes is around 3424 and 13696 respectively (100A one and 25 A one)

Comment: Protocol database: http://www.2dmatpedia.org/query?collection=2dmaterials&search_string=top-down

Comment: You really should not have an energy difference unless something about your particular system is causing it.  If you cannot provide a more complete input then we probably won't be able to help.

Comment: About the larger number of plane waves, this is to be expected: plane waves are an extended basis that "fill" the vacuum (unlike localized basis that don't). So for a plane wave calculation, the larger the vacuum the larger the number of plane waves. Specifically for VASP, you can find further details here: https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/Energy_cut_off_ENCUT_FFT_mesh.html

Comment: Since most of the number of plane waves cause by the applied large vacuum on the direction, can I justify using the lower number of plane waves (`NBANDS`) for following GW calculation? Because of the memory issues.

Comment: NBANDS is not the same as number of plane waves. The plane waves determine the size of the basis on which you are expanding the wave function. In practice, DFT codes typically don't diagonalize the entire Hamiltonian matrix, but instead only obtain the lowest-lying eigenvalues. NBANDS determines the number of eigenvalues you obtain, not the number of plane waves in the calculation.

Comment: Yeah but for the NBANS it asks to put number of maximum plane waves from standart DFT calculation for MP2 calculation for example: https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/MP2_calculations

Answer (score 4):

> I guess what your calculation is not done correctly.

I have run the self-consistent calculation with VASP. For the first structure, I obtain the energy is
$$\boxed{-18.438584 (\text{eV})}$$

For the second structure, I obtain the energy is:
$$\boxed{-18.438713 (\text{eV})}$$

The energy difference between the two structures is negligible. So the first vacuum space in the $z$-direction is good to obtain the converged results.

> Is there a protocol to follow for 2D materials calculations in VASP?

- This website: http://www.2dmatpedia.org/

Comment: Yeah, probably my calculation was not correct. Thanks for the calculation! I have another question; due to the plane waves, when you use larger vacuum space it produces a larger number of maximum plane waves which is equal to NBANDS input for further GW, MP2 calculations and it causes. How can I justify using a lower number of NBANDS with larger vacuum geometry?

Comment: For example, for 25A vacuum spaced geometry it finds around 3400 maximum plane waves but for 100 A one it finds about 13600 (4times). Can I use 3400 maximum plane waves for 100A geometry since these geometries are equivalent in principle?

Comment: Why you don't use the 25 $A$ geometry with 3400 maximum plane waves? If you just want more plane waves and more NBANDS in your calculation, you should increase cutoff energy rather than the vacuum space.

Comment: Yeah I could use but, I already have geometries with vacuum space of 100A, so I have to make calculations with them...

Comment: @Alfred From my experience, 100 $A$ is too much.

Comment: Apparently, yeah it's too much for plane wave calculations

Comment: +1. Thanks for doing this calculation for the user! I don't know if you use GitHub, but we have a place where we post output files for calculations we do for this site: https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters. In this case the question is #2301, but don't worry about it if it's not necessary to post the output files. This comment is just a notification about what's possible, in case you want to do it this time or next time.